# Как разместить UICollectionView внутри UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

Есть задача - сделать скроллящийся экран, который состоит из слайдера, кнопки и списка продуктов. Слайдер реализован с помощью `ContainerView` которое содержит `UIPageViewController`. Проблема в том, что если я размещаю все элементы (слайдер, кнопку и `UICollectionView` с продуктами) внутри `ScrollView`, то `UICollectionView` схлопывается. Если Я размещаю слайдер и кнопку внутри `UICollectionView` то компилятор ругается что нельзя размещать контейнер в элементах которые могут копироваться в рантайме

> error: Illegal Configuration: Container Views cannot be placed in
>   elements that are repeated at runtime.

Насколько я помню в андроиде был следующий trick - задать программно высоту для `RecyclerView` (аналог `UIContainerView`), что позволяло `RecyclerView` иметь постоянную для каждого конкретного случая и полностью вписываться в рамки `ScrollView`. Каким образом подобное можно реалтзовать в iOS?

Comment: что такое слайдер?

Comment: Прошу прощения - Это View, которое показывает изображения. В данном случае проект - интернет магазин - а изображения - слайды - это различные предложения от него - каждый слайд содержит изображение, титл, сабтитл и ссылку на то, что он описывает. Слайдер меняет слайды кажые n секунд + есть возможность переключать слайды свайпом - реализовал с помощью UIPageViewController

Comment: попробуйте еще раз объяснить иерархию - контейнер, в нем UIPageVC, а нем же UICollectionView, и в нем же кнопка?

Comment: Нет, главный VC содержит CollectionView, который содержит в первых двух ячейках UIPageVC  и кнопку (эти ячейки растянуты на ширину экрана) , а в остальных продукты (по две ячейки в секции). В этом случае компилятор отказывается собирать приложение ругаясь на контейнер. Либо я могу разместить все в общем ScrollView сначала UIPageVC, ниже кнопку, а ниже CollectionView с продуктами, но в этом случае CollectionView схлопывается т.к. располагается в ScrollView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первую очередь у вашего UICollectionView необходимо выключить скролл.

> В Interface Builder: **Scroll View** > Scrolling > Scrolling Enabled.

Далее нужно создать height-констранту и обновлять её при необходимости, допустим во viewWillAppear: вот так:

```
collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height
```

Comment: А в таком случае контент будет скроллиться?

Comment: @iamthevoid collectionView будет растянут по размеру содержимого. Всё будет скроллиться средствами scrollView.

Comment: А, понял, я по какой то причине решил, что Вы говорите о выключении скролла у UIScrollView)) Спасибо, это действительно решает проблему